# Prewarming EBS Volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a use case where we need to prewarm 1TB EBS volume created from snapshot of **already warmed** EBS volume, the problem we see with this activity is delay in prewarming which probably takes 8-9 hours, so Is there any different way to complete this action quickly?

Comment: Is warming up the new volume necessary?  Volumes warm themselves up over time, anyway, so unless you ultimately gain a significant advantage from the process, you could be just as well off not bothering with it. If you need to do a lot of reading right away, you may be impairing performance by trying to simultaneously warm it up and use it.  What have you found, comparing a warmed volume to one that isn't?  Is the EC2 instance a small one or a large one?

Comment: Instance type is r3.2xlarge and our EBS volumes are actually data directories for mysql, it will be one of the live slave of production data.